# Apply discount on cart

Tags: magento-1.9

I need your help for creating price rule for shopping cart

I want to give a customer 100 $ discount if they buy 3 items with subtotal above or equal 400 $ .if the items on the cart is from category 82 then the price rule should not work

condition 
f ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
Subtotal  equals or greater than  400
Total Items Quantity  greater than  2

Action 
If ALL  of these conditions are FALSE :
Category  is  82

the issue now if the customers add three items where the total above 400 $ and one of these items or two is belong to category 82  here the price will applied which actually I don't need it

e.g Item 1 = 50 $ can apply the rule 
item 2 40 $ can apply the rule 
then item 3 = 320 $ can't apply the rule >> from category 82

on that case the rule shouldn't apply although the subtotal is above 400 and the total qty is above 3 .. but actually the item which allow to get the discount not making my condition true 
item qty here is 2 
subtotal for this 2 items is less than 400 $

is there away to solve this issue  ???

Answer (score 1):

As per your conditions, i have created one cart rule which works perfect. here it goes. [image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: I try your solution but still not work .. the price rule will be applied if one item from category 82 is there  and the other 2 items from another category which is not correct we should have at least 3 items from any other category and the subtotal for these item is above 400 $